# Retrieve data from external api and show in django admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-custom-field

How to display data from external service in Django admin?Rather than querying a local database I would like to use an external API to retrieve the data to display in the django admin

class Order(models.Model):

```
service = models.ForeignKey('Service', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='orders')
number = models.CharField(...)
creation_date = models.DateTimeField(...)
...
```

@register(Order,site=admin_site)

class OrderAdmin(ImportExportMixin, SimpleHistoryAdmin):

1. Perform the API call instead of the database lookup and show data from API in orders model in admin panel.

Is there any way to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

May be [dadfes](https://github.com/estin/django-admin-data-from-external-service) ?

Check out demo app